# toggle between sorted list and original list React.js

Tags: reactjs, sorting, toggle

I'm trying to toggle between a descending ordered list then back to the original list that was rendered before sorting the list. The code is currently changing the original list upon clicking the sort button but does not return to the original list when clicked again. It stays in the sorted order.

```
class NonProfitContainer extends Component {

    state = {
        asc: true
    }

    
    toggleSort = () => {
         let originalList = this.props.nonprofits.map(np => <NonprofitList key={np.id} nonprofit={np}/>)
         let sortedList = this.props.nonprofits.sort((a, b) => b.name.localeCompare(a.name)); 

        this.setState({
            nonprofits: this.state.asc
              ? originalList
              : sortedList,
            asc: !this.state.asc,
          });

    };

    render(){

        const { asc } = this.state    
    
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <button onClick={() => this.toggleSort()}>{asc ? 'Sort Z-A' : 'Back'}</button>
                <hr/>
                {this.props.nonprofits.map(np => <NonprofitList key={np.id} nonprofit={np}/>)}
                <hr/>
                <h3>Add A New Nonprofit:</h3><br/>
                <NonprofitForm />
            </div>
        )
    }
} 

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        nonprofits: state.nonprofitReducer.nonprofits,
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{getNonprofits})(NonProfitContainer)
```

Any advice would be appreciated! I'm pretty new to react.

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting the props.nonprofits directly, you need to copy the values to another variable, sort it and if you want the original one, just copy that one.

You might need to use componentDidUpdate if you are getting values from redux to setState, just google it and you will get the idea.   This code will cover your sorting issue.

https://codepen.io/ktdev/pen/abBwzvo

```
const NonprofitList = (props) => {
  return <h1>{props.nonprofit.id}</h1>;
};

class Card extends React.Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    nonprofits: [
      { id: 1, name: "a" },
      { id: 2, name: "b" },
      { id: 3, name: "c" }
    ]
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      asc: true,
      nonprofits: props.nonprofits
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ darkMode: !this.state.darkMode });
  }

  toggleSort = () => {


    let sortedList = [...this.props.nonprofits];

    sortedList.sort((a, b) => b.name.localeCompare(a.name));
    this.setState({
      nonprofits: this.state.asc ? sortedList : this.props.nonprofits,
      asc: !this.state.asc
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { asc } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <button onClick={() => this.toggleSort()}>
          {asc ? "Sort Z-A" : "Back"}
        </button>
        <hr />
        {this.state.nonprofits.map((np) => (
          <NonprofitList key={np.id} nonprofit={np} />
        ))}
        <hr />
        <h3>Add A New Nonprofit:</h3>
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const el = document.querySelector("#root");
ReactDOM.render(<Card title="Example Component" />, el);
```